# Mysql: Select range between dates and adding extra rows (not days) to the range

Tags: mysql

I have a table with dates and prices in it and I'm trying to select a range between two dates but I also want to add n extra rows after the end date.

This is a sample of the data:

```
2013-01-09  29.67,
2013-01-08  29.51,
2013-01-07  28.69,
2013-01-04  28.01,
2013-01-03  27.88,
2013-01-02  27.44,
2012-12-31  26.20,
```

For example I'm doing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $table_name 
WHERE date between '2013-01-09' AND '2013-01-04' 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

What I'm trying to do is add 3 rows extra (not days because as you can see they are not sequential) so something like 2013-01-04 plus 3 rows to end up at 2012-12-31.

I hope I was clear, because even just explaining the problem is hard, imagine trying to find a solution online!

---

Update as requested.

So I'll try to rephrase and simplify the problem I'm having.  Forget everything I've written so far and start with a new point of view. I'll break the problem I'm having into 2 steps. Also I will use easier numbers as an example. The new data table:

```
2013-01-09  7
2013-01-08  1
2013-01-07  9
2013-01-04  1
2013-01-03  8
2013-01-02  5
2012-31-12  6
```

I want to calculate the average of these values for a given *date range*. So if the data range is 2013-01-09 to 2013-01-03 and the average for period 2 the able would look like this:

```
2013-01-09  7  4
2013-01-08  1  5
2013-01-07  9  5
2013-01-04  1  4.5
2013-01-03  8  6.5
2013-01-02  5  NA
```

To do this I have no problems. The problem arises here. Note that for the first date of the range I can not calculate the average of period 2 because I have no data select before it.  So the question is, how do I select 1 extra point after the date range (in particular the data from 2012-31-12) so I can calculate the average also for2013-01-02?

Thanks for the time guys.

Comment: Sorry, not clear. Show an example of what you want the table results to look like, at least. Why are you doing this?

Comment: If the data doesn't exist in the database, why are you trying to do this in the database layer of your application?

Comment: Please don't tell us you're trying to create an html table with blank rows at the bottom... I'm really concerned that's what you're doing. Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this on the database side, you can create a date table. You would then fetch the range that you wish and join prices on the date.

Comment: @OP, and this is the ONLY way you can do this. You can't fabricate data that doesn't exist in the middle of a query.

Answer (score 0):

Update on the question because from the comments it seems I really wasn't clear at all.

This is not html or anything strange.  I'm writing a php script that goes some mathematical calculations on the price column.

For this calculation I need to get n number of days and go an average based on a date range.

However, the problem is I need to select a few extra days beyond the date range. For example, if my range is from 2013-01-04 to 2013-01-09 I also need to add 3 extra data points which in this case takes me to 2013-12-31.

The question is, in MySql, how do I select a range of dates PLUS n number of rows beyond that range.  Unfortunately, I do not have ID column.  Hope this was clearer.

Comment: part of what you're being really unclear about is how the hell 3 extra data points takes you to 2013-12-31. Also, I told you to put an example of what your table should look like when you're done, which would have helped, and you failed to do that. ALSO, this update should be an edit to the question, not an answer.

Comment: Also, you could almost certainly find a way to do this in PHP, not sure why you're trying to do it in MySQL. Though I suspect it's not even necessary, but I'd have to know what you're calculating